# Flutter Application fails running after adding "local_auth" library

Tags: flutter, fingerprint, flutter-dependencies

I'm using `local_auth: 0.4.0+1` library in my Flutter project because I need it for 
 Fingerprint Authentication, the problem is when I run it this warning appears:

```
*********************************************************

WARNING: This version of local_auth will break your Android build if it or its dependencies aren't compatible with AndroidX.
         See  for more information on the problem and how to fix it.
         This warning prints for all Android build failures. The real root cause of the error may be unrelated.    
         *********************************************************
```

And then this failure occurs:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
 Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:328: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:328: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\emami\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\8e7abbb87897c27c7928ae79da9182a2\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.example.flutterapp\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\emami\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-27.1.1.aar\2118f8390bba553635fd03361d6fcc0d\res\values\values.xml:96:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\emami\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-27.1.1.aar\2118f8390bba553635fd03361d6fcc0d\res\values\values.xml:96:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\emami\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\8e7abbb87897c27c7928ae79da9182a2\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.example.flutterapp\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\emami\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My Flutter SDK is following:
`sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"`
What is the problem and how can I fix it?
I guess may be it's because of conflict with my Flutter SDK and `local_auth` version.

Comment: The version of this plugin you are using requires you to migrate the project to AndroidX https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

Comment: You also need to use compile SDK 28 as that resource was only added in 28.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was exactly because of version incompatibility of Flutter SDK and `local_auth` library, I changed it to `local_auth: 0.3.0` and the error was gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Let `MainActivity` inherit the `FlutterFragmentActivity` and add the `support-v4` package to `build.gradle`, or use `androidx`. Can refer to [the example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/local_auth/example)